# Sitecore Azure Deployment failed

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-azure

I am deploying Sitecore website using Sitecore Azure and during deployment it failed and displayed the error:

> Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer
>   failed System.ApplicationException:
>   AdvaiyaWebSiteTestScusCe01Role01SSc437Staging [S]
>   Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer
>   failed ---> System.ApplicationException:
>   Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer is
>   failed --->
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.SqlServerManagementException:
>   Trying to create new server from a database that alreay has a database
>   server. New server name 'c562zrxbm0' is not the same as existing
>   'd5izyq3l5o' at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Managers.AzureManagers.AzureSqlManager.CreateDataBaseServer(String
>   subscriptionID, AzureSqlDatabase database, String login, String
>   password) at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Managers.AzureManagers.AzureSqlManager.CreateDataBaseServer(AzureSqlDatabase
>   azureSqlDatabase, String login, String password) at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer.ResolveServer(AzureSqlDatabase
>   azureSqlDb, List`1 resolvedServers, Dictionary`2 preferServer) at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer.Action(RolePipelineArgsBase
>   args) at
>   Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.BasePipeline.RolePipelineProcessor.Process(RolePipelineArgsBase
>   args) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---

Any idea about the error? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you tried to make a deployment after a previous deployment that has been failed. Please clean up a failed deployment as described in the following article and then try a new one.

https://github.com/olegburov/sitecore-azure-content/blob/master/articles/how-to-clean-up-a-failed-sitecore-azure-deployment.md